# JS - How to get and calculate the current date

Tags: javascript

Sorry, but what is the fastest way to display the current date?

```
 2014-01-18 Saturday 12:30
```

with this function or how do it the right way?

```
 var d=new Date();
 var t=d.getTime();
```

Comment: `Date().valueOf();` [Date MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Comment: Also, look at [Where can I find documentation on formatting a date in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/where-can-i-find-documentation-on-formatting-a-date-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var d =  new Date();
alert(d.toString());
```

Comment: Just a note: there's no need to explicitly use `.toString()`

Comment: true but here I have just given `.toString()` for to be in safe side.
I assumed there would be further operations on the variable like storing in some other variable or smthing.... So depends on the use case

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
var d = new Date();
var dd = d.getDate();
var mm = d.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
var yy = d.getFullYear();

var weekday=new Array(7);
weekday[0]="Sunday";
weekday[1]="Monday";
weekday[2]="Tuesday";
weekday[3]="Wednesday";
weekday[4]="Thursday";
weekday[5]="Friday";
weekday[6]="Saturday";

var day=weekday[d.getDay()];

var h = d.getHours();
    var m = d.getMinutes();

alert(yy+"-"+mm+"-"+dd+" "+day+" "+h+":"+m)
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/LqB3n/)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind the format, you can do it in one line:

```
''+new Date()
```

You only need to use a `Date` object as a string, in order to implicitly call its [`.toString()`](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_Section_15.htm#ELS5_Section_15.9.5.2) method, which

> returns a String value. The contents of the String are
>   implementation-dependent, but are intended to represent the Date in
>   the current time zone in a convenient, human-readable form.

Answer (score 1):

```
new Date().toGMTString()
```

It's something similar to what you are looking for

If you want complicate the output you can get element by element and format yourself the date (or you can use Globalize.js)